# How to test if a particular FileType has syntax for folds predefined?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding

I wish to automatically set my `foldmethod` to manual if syntax fold definitions are not defined for a particular Filetype. However, I am unsure how to check if the fold syntax is defined for the Filetype.

I could manually load the file, and type `:syn` to get all syntax and look for the fold syntax definiton, but this is tedious to do with all Filetypes supported by vim.  How can I do this programmatically?  Do I need to use redir of the `:syn` output, and grep that output for the word "fold"?  Surely, there has to be a better way.

Comment: I'm afraid the information you are looking for is not exposed anywhere else than in the output of `:syntax`.